# Font Style Picker Control for OSX Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want to know if there is default system control that can be used to let the user select Font Type, Size and Style.

If there is a way to use font picker as XCode uses to let developers edit the font of label controls for example that would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The default menu bar has a Format menu.

Comment: I'm making dialog that edit shape object, for example if the user want to edit text object the dialog should have edit font capability, I don't want to achieve so from the menu.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were looking for the whole panel.